# How to add dynamic n checkbox columns to gridview ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

Ex: `mypage.aspx?num=xxx`

How can I add a `num` checkbox column to **Gridview** in mypages by code-behind?

I had added `num` columns to **Datatable** with parameter `typeof(bool)` but when I loaded mypage, the checkboxes were disabled so I can't check them.

Comment: check my answer it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my grid aspx code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>           
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

First of all add `num` number of template fields to your gridview

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num = Request.QueryString["num"];

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
        tf.HeaderText = "Status";
        gv.Columns.Add(tf);
    }        
}
```

After adding template feilds, now we will add checkboxes to the gridview. We write a function to add checkboxes. Below is the code

```
private void AddCheckBox()
{
    int num = Request.QueryString["num"];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                cb.Checked = true;                  
                row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(cb);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now place this function in your grid databound event.

```
protected void gv_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddCheckBox();
}
```

At the end also call the function in the page load event so first time when grid loads it shows checkboxes are checked

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        AddCheckBox();
    } 
}
```

**To check my code:**
I add a bound feild to grid view and bind the grid view with a datatable:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Data" HeaderText="Data" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and in code behind in **page_load** event i add the following code

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Data");

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = "Test";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    gv.DataSource = dt;
    gv.DataBind();
```

and also made 1 change in the function AddCheckBox as

```
for (int i = 1; i < num + 1; i++)
```

The above change is made because I have a databound feild at index 0 of the grid view columns so I changed it to start from 1.

and here is the result ( page output )

```
Data    Status  Status  Status  Status  Status  Status  Status  Status  Status  Status
Test    Checked Checked Checked Checked Checked Checked Checked Checked Checked Checked
```

Checked is used for checkbox is checked

Comment: @WaqarJanjua have you found that the more dynamic columns you add the worse the performance?

Comment: @Princa you are right, because dynamic columns will be created/destroyed on every request, utilizing more resources than the columns added in aspx code at design time

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Request.QueryString["num"]
```

to get the value of num in the URL. Then iterate num times, adding a CheckBoxField to your GridView each time.