# GridView CheckBox column in Web UI custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, code-behind

I'm updating a customer Web UI control to include a GridView. In this GridView I require a check box column. Normally this is an easy task but placing the declaration in the aspx page however I need to be able to do it in the code behind.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is a `Customer Web ui control`, a `UserControl`? Where did you get stuck in your code? Show it.

Comment: Possible duplicate question. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685470/how-to-add-dynamic-n-checkbox-columns-to-gridview-asp-net